# How to determine the shape of a fully connected layer in Squeeze-and-Excitation Networks?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Given the following network with input $x=H\times W \times C$ where $H$ is the width, $W$ is the width and $C$ is the number of channels (as $x$ is originally output of a convolutional layer).

[image]

For $C$ channels, the dimension of average pooling would be $1 
\times 1 \times C$. Thne after passing it to the fully contented layer, the dimension is **reduced** by a ratio $r$ so that it becomes $1 
\times 1 \times \frac{C}{r}$.

**Question**: why the dimension of fully connected layer 1 becomes $1
\times 1 \times \frac{C}{r}$ please? From my understanding, the fully connected layer does not do any reduction of incoming input.

This comes from J. Hu, L. Shen and G. Sun, "Squeeze-and-Excitation Networks," 2018 IEEE/CVF Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, Salt Lake City, UT, USA, 2018, pp. 7132-7141, doi: 10.1109/CVPR.2018.00745.

A preprint is on arXiv: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.01507.pdf

Comment: Equation 3 from the paper, and the surrounding text, seems to answer this directly. As an example, suppose you have a matrix $A$ with shape $10 \times 11$ and a matrix $B$ with shape $11 \times 2$. What's the shape of $AB$?

Comment: @Sycorax. I think this is just a parameter they set, then they define the fully connected layer shape based on this hyperparameter $r$. Is my understanding correct, please? So the fully connected layer shape is defined automatically based on the value of $r$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I gather from the paper: choose some $r$, and then that choice sets the shape of the weight matrices. I think this is the "squeeze" that the title refers to, because $r > 1$ and $C/r < C$.

Comment: @Sycorax. Last question pleas. They mentioned that the excitation phase (fully connected layer, ReLU, Sigmoid) produces modulation weights. It's just mentioned once in the paper, but I am not sure what they mean by  modulation weights?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what that means either. I think it would be best to ask in its own Question. If you feel that you know the answer to the question you ask in this post, you can write your own answer to it.